# Heuristics for complex scheduling

Tags: algorithm, big-o, depth-first-search, path-finding, heuristics

A recent side project I've been playing around with is an attempt at a
generalized algorithm for scheduling problems. I find it interesting as I beleive it to be effectively pathfinding in a fundementally more complex enviroment.

Thus far I have implemented [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to solve the problem.

The only problem is... the O'notation is horrific ([my question in math exchange about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937110/figuring-out-big-onotation-of-a-naive-depth-first-search-scheduling-algorithm))([a desmos illustration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqepd161bz)):

[image]

(`t_{m,n}` is synonymous with `O(m,n)`)

Where `n` is the number of tasks (e.g. journeys) and `m` is the number of agents (e.g. taxis).

---

I have done some work in adding a basic heuristic which massively restricts the number of paths explored.

With 8 tasks and 5 agents by preventing exploration of certain paths where travelling the first edges takes more than a given time, I can restrict the task to produce results as such:

```
Hello, world!
time:   03:874
edges:
        max:     19,237,093,440
        actual:       7,838,526
        inline: 7838526        
        %:      0.040747       
min_time: 1954.00
```

Given 8 tasks and 5 agents there are 19.23 billion possible edges in the graph, the restriction leads to us only exploring/constructing 7.83 million of these.

While only having to explore 0.04% of the possibilities may seem decent, the O'notation is so bad that this fails to be good enough.

---

As can be seen in the desmos illustration, even with a small number of agents and tasks our O'notation crushes all others but `O(n!)` and `O(2^n)` (blue=factorial, red=exponential, most significant black dotted line representing `n=6` and `m=x`):

[image]

This worsens exponetially as we increase `n` or `m`, as such we need a massively restrictive heuristic capable of crushing the O'notation down to atleast `O(n^2)` for any practicality. The current one requires manual adjustment to scale and is unable to be restrictive enough.

---

The heuristic specifically here is to not explore a path if:

`d > 2.5 * SIZE / NUM_OF_AGENTS`.

Where:

- `d` is the time/distance required for a specific agent to begin a specific task (e.g. a taxi moving to a pickup location for a journey or time to pass memory to GPU)
- `SIZE` is half the maximum time/distance `d` could be.
- `NUM_OF_AGENTS` the constant in code for the number of agents (`m`).

---

As such my ultimate question is, what would be better heuristics for this problem? (or even entire approaches if you know of them)

---

- [The code](https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/scheduling)
- With any complex/interesting questions I am never sure where is best to ask them, here is the best I know of, if you find anything lacking drop a comment and I will try to fix it.
- Worth mentioning that a conception missed here is how one might consider such scheduling as pathfinding through a multidimensional space and then traditional algorithms might be more easily applied, I have yet to really attempt or figure out how to do this. If you do, I would greatly appreciated an illustration.

---

Comment: Sorry, I have difficulty to understand the relationship between the scheduling problem and your formula. With one agent (m=1) and two tasks (n = 2), how do you get a minimum time of 4? Naively, I would have expected a time of 2.

Comment: @Damien, In the 1st layer 1 agent can do task 1 or task 2, thus 2 edges, in the 2nd layer, the agent then must do the remaining task, thus 2 more edges (1 edge for each of the nodes from the 1st layer)(`(1*2)+((1*2)*(1*1))=4`). More generally the last layer only has 1 task remaining, so the number of children for each node is simply the number of agents, thus with 1 agent, each node has 1 child.

Comment: You seem to count a kind of  number of possibilities... If the agent does task 1 then task 2, he spends *two* units of time to perform the two tasks... I guess I did not undertand the problem at all. I may not be alone.

Comment: @Damien `he spends two units of time to perform the two tasks` I would rather say `2 decisions are being made`, since in systems with more than 1 agent, it would need to be decided which agent should do the last task (I think I may add some pseudo-code I know Rust code may be a bit dense to read for that).